# Understanding an example

Tags: python, pseudocode

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
            return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return [None, None]

def barnYard(heads, legs):
    pigs, chickens = solve(legs, heads)
    if pigs == None:
        print "There is no solution."
    else:
        print 'Number of pigs: ', pigs
        print 'Number of Chickens: ', chickens
```

I'm learning Python and came across this example, can someone please explain in plain english (or pseudo-code) what this is doing line by line.

Many thanks

Comment: Well... Python is mostly indented pseudo-code ;) . I can't see what in this code would be easier to understand in pseudo-code than in Python.

Comment: Right, I know its easy but I'm too dumb to figure it out. For a noob like me, its really difficult to figure out how functions work, whats going where and which block is being executed first etc..

Comment: Particularly, I don't understand why "+ 1" is used in: for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1)

Comment: range(0,3) would return [0,1,2]. The high number is not included in the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`solve` is computing how many chicks (1 head, 2 legs) and how many pigs (1 head, 4 legs) it takes to total up to the given numbers of heads and legs.

It uses a "brute force", that is, maximally simple, approach:

- it tries even possible number of
  chicks from none at all to as many as
  was specified as number of heads
  (that's the role of the loop `for
  numChicks in range(0, numHeads +
  1):`, since `range` gives integers
  from the starting value included
  to the ending value excluded);
- for each given `numChicks` it computes
  how many pigs there would be to give
  the requested number of heads, by the
  statement `numPigs = numHeads - numChicks`
- then it computes how many total legs
  those chicks and pigs would have, by
  `totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks`
- then it checks if the `totLegs` equal
  the requested number: if so, it returns
  a list with two items, the numbers of
  chicks and pigs that solve the problem
- lastly, if it "falls of the bottom" of
  the `for` loop without having returned
  a value yet, it knows there's no solution,
  and signifies that by returning a list
  each of whose two items is `None`.

`barnYard` just delegates the solution to `solve`, and prints it out in a nice readable way, either as "no solution" or as nicely decorated numbers of chicks and pigs.

Now, to keep progressing, ask yourself if `solve` could be written more efficiently. Clearly there is no solution if the number of legs is less than twice the number of heads, or more than four times the number of heads, or odd -- maybe `solve` could test for those case and return `[None, None]` immediately.  Could you code that...?

It may not be obvious, but every other combination of numbers of heads and legs has a solution -- and there IS a way to find it just by arithmetic, without looping. Think about it, maybe with the help of elementary middle-school algebra...

Comment: +1 for a good explanation, but your first bullet point should read "... as number of *heads* ..." , not " ... as number of legs ...". Fixing that for you.

Comment: And, as to a more efficient solution, it's not required until your number of pigs and/or chicks is well up in the millions :-) Some people try for efficiency for its own sake but forget that the real world doesn't always need it.

Comment: @Pax: Right, but since I'm learning (not looking to optimize my code for performance) it would be great to know. :)

Comment: Got it, finally! :) All answers were great, but yours was the most detailed. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Oh, just one thing: should'nt the variable numChicks be initialized before using in a loop?

Comment: @Nimbuz, `for avariable in something: ...` does already initialize `avariable` (to the first item of something, then the second one, and so forth).

Comment: @Pax, tx for the edit. As for efficiency, generally agreed, but lowering the big-O performance of an algorithm (here, from O(N) to O(1)) is crucial -- it lets you _scale_. Unless the N is specifically bound by a problem's specs, what today you think of running on hundreds of cases will tomorrow run on billions. 10% efficiency gains (or even bigger, but same big-O) may often not be worth bothering with... big-O lowering most always is. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time" -- and big-O reduction is (most of) the _other_ 3% of the time!-).

Answer (score 2):

Alex Martelli alludes to an algebraic solution which I'll include here for completeness. It can be worked out with the use of simultaneous equations. Being a simple mathematical solution, it's possibly faster, at least for *large* numbers of legs and heads :-)

Let:

- `H` be the number of heads;
- `L` be the number of legs;
- `C` be the number of chicks; and
- `P` be the number of pigs.

Given `C` and `P`, we can calculate the other two variables with:

```
H =  C +  P (1)
L = 2C + 4P (2)
```

I'll detail *every* step in the calculations below. The mathematically inclined can no doubt point out that steps could be combined but I'd prefer to be explicit. From (1), we can calculate:

```
   H = C + P
=> 0 = C + P - H       [subtract H from both sides]
=> 0 = H - C - P       [multiply both sides by -1]
=> P = H - C           [add P to both sides] (3)
```

and substitute that into (2):

```
    L = 2C + 4P
=>  L = 2C + 4(H - C)   [substitute H-C for P]
=>  L = 2C + 4H - 4C    [expand 4(H-C) to 4H-4C]
=>  L = 4H - 2C         [combine 2C-4C into -2C]
=>  0 = 4H - 2C - L     [subtract L from both sides]
=> 2C = 4H - L          [add 2C to both sides]
=>  C = 2H - L/2        [divide both sides by 2] (4)
```

Now you have two formulae, one that can calculate the number of chicks from head and legs `(4)`, the other which can calculate number of pigs from chicks and heads `(3)`.

So here's the Python code to do it, with appropriate checks to ensure you don't allow some of the more bizarre mathematical solutions, like 2 heads and 7 legs giving us a pig and a half along with half a chick, or 1 head and 12 legs giving 5 pigs and -4 chicks :-)

```
def solve (numLegs, numHeads):
    # Use the formulae (these make integers).
    chicks = numHeads * 2 - int (numLegs / 2)
    pigs = numHeads - chicks

    # Don't allow negative number of animals.
    if chicks < 0 or pigs < 0:
        return [None, None]

    # Don't allow fractional animals.
    if chicks * 2 + pigs * 4 != numLegs:
        return [None, None]
    if chicks + pigs != numHeads:
        return [None, None]

    return [pigs, chicks]
```

Of course, if you pass in fractional numbers of head or legs, all bets are off. Here's a complete test program so you can try out various values to ensure both methods return the same values:

```
import sys

def usage (reason):
    print "Error: %s"%(reason)
    print "Usage: solve <numHeads> <numLegs>"
    sys.exit (1);

def solve1 (numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range (0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2 * numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
            return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return [None, None]

def solve2 (numLegs, numHeads):
    chicks = numHeads * 2 - int (numLegs / 2)
    pigs = numHeads - chicks
    if chicks < 0 or pigs < 0:           return [None, None]
    if chicks * 2 + pigs * 4 != numLegs: return [None, None]
    if chicks + pigs != numHeads:        return [None, None]
    return [pigs, chicks]

if len (sys.argv) != 3:
    usage ("Wrong number of parameters (%d)"%(len (sys.argv)))

try:    heads = int (sys.argv[1])
except: usage ("Invalid <numHeads> of '%s'"%(sys.argv[1]))

try:    legs = int (sys.argv[2])
except: usage ("Invalid <numLegs> of '%s'"%(sys.argv[2]))

print "[pigs, chicks]:"
print "  ", solve1 (legs, heads)
print "  ", solve2 (legs, heads)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is iterating through every possible combination of pigs and chickens (with the specified number of heads) until it finds one that has the correct number of legs, and then returns the numbers of pigs and chickens. If it gets through each combination without finding a valid answer, it returns [None, None] to indicate failure.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, `solve` is iterating through every possible combination of chickens and pigs, and when it finds a match, returning it.)

NumChickens + NumPigs must equal NumHeads, so it checks every NumChickens from 0 to NumHeads (that's what `for range(0,NumHeads+1)` does), and sets NumPigs to be NumHeads-NumChickens.

From there, its just a matter of multiplying out the number of feet, and seeing if they match.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's trying to figure out the answer to the problem, "How many chickens and pigs are there in a barnyard if there are X heads and Y legs in the barnyard?"  The `for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):`code creates a variables numChicks, and cycles through it from numChicks = 0 to numChicks = numHeads.  (Note: the range function doesn't include the highest value).

For each number of numChicks, it checks to see if that numChicks and corresponding numPigs values comes up with the correct value of numLegs.  numHeads will always be correct since numChicks + numPigs = numHeads, but numLegs varies based on the distribution -- hence the loop.  If at any point the solution is found (when totLegs == numLegs), then that value is returned.  If the entire loop gets done and no solution was found, then the list [None, None] is returned, meaning that there's no solution for this input.